# Order of an initialization in inline initialization. C/C++

Tags: c++, c, initialization

Here is the code I am concerned with:

```
double first(2), second(first);
```

Will the first variable always be initialized before a second one?

Comment: Why do you care? What's the problem?

Comment: If you're that concerned, why not just put the declarations on separate lines?

Comment: I don't C C here! Why do you tag unrelated languages?

Comment: I hope the answers to this question cite the relevant parts of the language specification.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, I am learning C/C++ and I consider an understanding of such fundamental questions to be a vital part of knowing the language.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, why don`t you see a C language here? Is not it possible to initialize a variable in C in such a way?

Comment: @KABoissonneault, I would like to know what is under hood in the case, since I am gonna use a lot of initializations during my C/C++ exploitation.

Comment: @ЯрикТроф Not with that particular syntax, I dont do C but when I put it in the online compiler it wouldnt accept it, but it did accept: `double first = 2, second = first;`

Comment: @Borgleader, so is there no such a way to initialize a variable in C?

Comment: @ЯрикТроф you're using **C++ constructor initialization**. And C and C++ are very much distinct languages.

Comment: @ЯрикТроф: I'm of the opinion that if you know the answer to this question, then you know entirely *too much* about C++. Remember: people will read your code far more than you will write it. Making it clear and idiot-proof is more important than knowing dark, esoteric corners of the language.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, thank you very much for the attention!

Comment: @NicolBolas, thank you very much for the attention!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, but still. What is an answer to my question?